# How do I get the Preferences option in Totem 3.6 on Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: unity, appmenu, totem

I have upgraded my Ubuntu 12.10 with the GNOME 3 PPA (ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3). This has updated Totem to version 3.6.2. Since GNOME 3.6 has introduced its own global menus, I cannot find the Preferences option in Totem's menu now. I am using the default Unity global menu system. Any ideas on how to get Preferences back?

Comment: i'm not in gnome, but have you tried "h" key, it usually shows/hides controls?

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal and launch Totem like this:

```
UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 totem
```

This will disable the global menu for Totem, so the menu that used to show up on the top Unity panel will show up inside the Totem window, but the GNOME "Gmenu" will now show up on the op panel - click it and there you should find the preferences menu along with a few other items.

Screenshot:

[image]

To always run Totem like this, open its desktop file as root:
gksu gedit /usr/share/applications/totem.desktop

And change "Exec=totem %U" (it should be on line 5) to "UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 totem %U", then save the file.

Via: [How To Disable The GNOME Shell AppMenu While Retaining Its Functionality](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/02/how-to-disable-gnome-shell-appmenu.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have a running machine with Unity Desktop and Totem 3.6. *(but wiht global menu disable)*
As you can see the menu bar is in the Totem's window, but also in unity I have a global menu called "**Videos > Preferences**".

[image]

Or you can set the focus on the totem's window,then use the **"Hud"** *(press the `Alt` key)* and type for "Preferences", then hit enter and the preferences windows will be open.

[image]

[image]

Tested with "global menu enable" the **"Hud**" brings the "preferences window"
[image]

Hope this will helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you really need the menu back, you could downgrade `totem` and all it's sub-packages and plugins, to version `3.4.3-0ubuntu5` and lock the version from any updates. Launch `Synaptic`, search for totem and select all *totem* 3.6.* files, go to *Force verion*, then mark the files as **Locked** in the *Package* menu.